# ngFor display custom message if empty if data from pipe fitler is empty in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a component

```
<div *ngIf="(StatementData$ | async) as stmtData; else stillLoading">
  <div *ngFor="let p of plans">
    <h3>{{p.planShortName}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let s of stmtData.documents | PlanCodePipe : p.planCode">
      <span *ngIf="!s.isDownloading"><a (click)="fetchDocument(s);" class="click-link">{{s.label}}</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have a pipe filter PlanCodePipe

```
export class PlanCodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], planCode: string): any {
    // console.log("in pipe for", sectionType);
    if (!items) return [];
    return items.filter(x => x.planCode === planCode);
  }
}
```

like u see in my component , sometimes this filter results in 0 matches.

```
<div *ngFor="let s of stmtData.documents | PlanCodePipe : p">
```

(it filters the documents based on the current plan code from the outer loop)
how to catch that and put "No Statements"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe inside your script and return it.

**Template**

```
{{ isNoResults(stmtData.documents, p) ? 'NO RESULTS' : p.planShortName }}
```

**Script**

```
isNoResults(documents, p){
  let pipe = new PlanCodePipe();
  let transform = pipe.transform(documents, p.planCode);
  return transform?.length == 0;
}
```

Comment: return transform?.length == 0; is giving me error saying expression expected

Comment: Also 'no results' doesnt have to be where the planShortName is .. i can be within the div or below that